# What Content-Type are Voice Memo files on iOS?

Tags: ios, content-type, voice

In IOS, if you take a Voice Memo, you can Save To Files it from the share dialog. This puts it on your iphone as a file.

I am building a mobile web form with a file picker. I am trying to make it so that the accept= of the file picker will pick up voice memo files.

Currently, accept="audio/*" does NOT allow selection of the voice memo file.
Accept="*" does.

So the correct answer must be that the content-type is some other content type and not audio/*. Can anybody shed light on what it is?

Answer (score 0):

Testing with https://htmlstrip.com/mime-file-type-checker on my iPhone, recorded a voice file, saved file and uploaded, this site tells me its:

```
audio/x-m4a
```

Also perhaps the component/lib for the file picker you're using doesn't support the particular filetype, or it's filtering it internally. Not sure what you're using there, but in vanilla HTML this seems doable